# Using sofa api with the most simple express server

Tags: express, graphql, sofa-api

`Hi`.
I have this most simple express graphql server.
I want to use `sofa-api` to make it "rest-able".

Two problems:

1. when you go to `/api/hello` it should say "Hello World!", now its null. the `/graphql` route does work correctly and return "Hello World!".
2. The rest swagger interface is not loading at `/api`
   you can play with it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-p6jnji?file=index.js,package.json

```js
var schema = buildSchema(`
type Query{
    hello:String
}`);

const openApi = OpenAPI({
  schema,
  info: {
    title: 'Example API',
    version: '3.0.0',
  },
});

var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello World!';
  },
};

var app = express();
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  '/api',
  useSofa({
    schema,
    basePath: '/api',
    onRoute(info) {
      openApi.addRoute(info, {
        basePath: '/api',
      });
    },
  })
);

writeFileSync('./swagger.json', JSON.stringify(openApi.get(), null, 2));
app.listen(4400);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no root value defined in Sofa.
In `graphqlHttp` call, you provide `rootValue` as an execution parameter but Sofa is not aware of that

I assume the most elegant way is to build your schema with the resolvers (`root value`)

something like this:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

You can find more info [here](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/tools/docs/generate-schema)

Comment: Thanks. but how to I introduce it to sofa? any chance you can fix the example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-p6jnji?file=index.js,package.json

Comment: oh no markdown in the comments :)
I edited my initial response and added some info